# Snowflake selecting item in a list of nested jsons without flattening

Tags: sql, list, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Given the following input data:

```
{
  "class": "history"
  "students": [
      {"first_name": "joe", last_name: "doe", "age": 16},
      {"first_name": "tony", last_name: "helen", "age": 10},
      {"first_name": "erica", last_name: "kran", "age": 12},
  ]
}

{
  "class": "math"
  "students": [
      {"first_name": "joe", last_name: "no", "age": 16},
      {"first_name": "yo", last_name: "wha", "age": 18},
      {"first_name": "dan", last_name: "test", "age": 12},
  ]
}
```

In elasticsearch you can query this data and fetch the "first_name" attribute of the nested value students, without splitting into separate rows, so the result would look like:

```
class   | first_name
-------------------------------
history | ['joe', 'tony', 'erica']
math    | ['joe', 'yo', 'dan']
```

However I can't find a way to achieve something similar in snowflake, without making a rather complex query with flattening and then grouping by again which seems like an overkill.

Is there a way in snowflake to query a nested json list key, and keeping all the values in the same row in a list, or at least get the original list of jsons, but only with the "first_name" key and not the whole object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript UDF to do this. You'll still need to flatten to the level you want the values, but you won't have to flatten to extract the repeating values from the array. Here's an example:

```
create or replace function ARRAY_EXTRACT_BY_KEY(ARR array, KEY_NAME string)
returns array
language javascript strict immutable
as
$$
    out = [];
    for (let i=0; i<ARR.length; i++){
        out.push(ARR[i][KEY_NAME]);
    }
    return out;
$$;

with JSON as
(
select parse_json($$[{
    "class": "history",
    "students": [{"first_name": "joe","last_name": "doe","age": 16
        },
        {
            "first_name": "tony","last_name": "helen","age": 10
        },
        {
            "first_name": "erica","last_name": "kran","age": 12
        }
    ]
}, {
    "class": "math",
    "students": [{"first_name": "joe","last_name": "no","age": 16
        },
        {"first_name": "yo","last_name": "wha","age": 18
        },
        {"first_name": "dan","last_name": "test","age": 12
        }
    ]
}]$$) V
)
select   VALUE:class::string as CLASS
        ,ARRAY_EXTRACT_BY_KEY(VALUE:students, 'first_name') as FIRST_NAMES
from JSON, table(flatten(V));
```

Output:

| CLASS | FIRST_NAMES |
| --- | --- |
| history | [ "joe", "tony", "erica" ] |
| math | [ "joe", "yo", "dan" ] |

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there is a simple way to achieve this without any fancy functions and workarounds. It seems pretty trivial as elastic supports it easily